# Como alterar o campo de uma tabela, tendo como referencia valores de outra tabela. Usando cakephp 1.3

Tags: php, oracle, cakephp, phpstorm

Tenho uma associação de tabelas `projeto > auto > anexo`. Na tabela projeto tenho um field `cod_status`, e na tabela anexo tenho um field `status`. 
Como faço para que quando eu edite o field `Anexo.status` para 'I', o `Projeto.cod_status` seja alterado para `5` automaticamente.

Edit do controller

```
   function edit($id = null)
{
    if (!$id && empty($this->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(sprintf(__('%s inválido.', true), 'Anexo'));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        if ($this->Anexo->save($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(sprintf(__('%s alterado com sucesso.', true), 'Anexo'), 'default', array('class' => 'success'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(sprintf(__('O %s não pode ser salvo. Por favor, tente novamente.', true), 'anexo'));
        }
    }
    if (empty($this->data)) {
        $this->data = $this->Anexo->read(null, $id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apenas checando se nos dados para salvar o teu campo está com o valor desejado e fazer uma condição para que caso esteja, salve o Projeto também, acredito que funcione:

dentro do teu `if ($this->Anexo->save($this->data)) {` insira o seguinte código conforme operação que citei acima.

```
if ($this->data['status'] === 'l'){
  $this->Projeto->set(array('cod_status' => 5));
  $this->Projeto->save();
}
```

Talvez o formato dos dados em `$this->Data` seja diferente de apenas um array com os campos do modelo em questão, e se for, favor debugar e alterar para que encaixe neste formato, pode ser que seja algo como `$this->data['Anexo']['status']` também.